# How to get the LC from a transfer function while given a crossover frequency (low pass RLC filter)

Tags: transfer-function, passive-filter

[image: (1/LC) / (s^2 + s*(1/RC) + (1/LC))]

I have made the transfer equation for a low-pass RLC filter, but I'm having trouble on what to do next to get L and C. (I also have a bandpass and high-pass filter I need to do, but I just need one explained, then I think I can manage the rest.)

For sake of simplicity, let's say R = 10 ohms, the lower crossover frequency is 100 Hz, and the higher crossover frequency is 1 kHz.

I'm a bit confused if it's possible to get L and C from this much information, or if I simply need to make a reasonable choice for L or C (like L = 1 mH or C = 10uF) and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough to have the corner frequency as the only requirement (and the R), because, as you can see from your transfer function, the quality factor is dependent on C. Thus, L=1m C=1u will not be the same as L=1u C=1m. Once you have your quality factor, Q, or the damping, ζ, you can use whatever way feels easier for you to solve for L and C. For example:

$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\dfrac{1}{RC}s+\dfrac{1}{LC}}=\dfrac{\omega^2}{s^2+\dfrac{\omega}{Q}s+\omega^2} \tag{1}
$$

From here, a system of two equations is formed:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
\omega^2&=\dfrac{1}{LC} \\
Q&=\omega RC \\
\end{aligned}\right. \tag{2}$$

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
L&=\dfrac{R}{\omega Q} \\
C&=\dfrac{Q}{\omega R}
\end{aligned}\right. \tag{3}$$

Suppose you want a Bessel response, unscaled. Then Q=1/√3, and for R=50 Ω, f=1 kHz => L=13.78 mH and C=1.84 μF. It's useless to talk about a stopband frequency since you have a fixed 2nd order filter which has a fixed slope of -40 dB/dec.

Comment: I just got to my bode plots and realized that the " L=1m C=1u will not be the same as L=1u C=1m." thing. Thanks for the information! This clears things up!

Though I do have one more question, how would I solve the problem with ζ instead of Q?

Comment: @Anthony What is the relation between \$\zeta\$ and Q? You must know this.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The OP is talking about the **crossover frequency** not the corner/cut-off frequency.

Comment: @Carl OP asked specifically for that, but it doesn't make sense to ask for fc at two frequencies in a lowpass. Also OP's hesitance in seeing the relation between \$\zeta\$ and Q. That's why I understand it to mean corner/cut-off frequency. But you're right, and for OP: the cross-over frequency is the point where the magnitude crosses the 0 dB line, which is different than the corner/cut-off frequency, which is the -3 dB point for 1st order and Butterworth filters (or a convenient mid-point for the phase). For a high-Q filter, the gain might cross twice, but then the falling edge matters.

Answer (score 2):

Compute Q = 0.58 for Bessel

For 8 Ohms 100Hz LPF = 17.2 mH air core.   C= 90 uF non-polar

For 1kHz HPF C = 14.1 uF , C = 1.8 mH R= 8.

For mid-band fc= sqrt(10 * 1k)= 316 Hz BW= 1k-100= 900 Hz

Result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, if you are given simply this equation and the value of R (with no other requirements) then you should make a reasonable choice for \$L\$ or \$C\$ and then calculate the remaining unknown value.

Comment: Wait, doesn't 1/LC = omega^2? why couldn't you use that as a replacement, so the only variable would be C? After you get C, you can do 1/LC = omega^2 and find L. I just thought of this now.

Comment: Sure, make a choice for either one and then calculate the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all we need to solve the following equation to solve for the maximum:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\omega_0}\left(\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|\right)=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_0=\dots\tag1$$

Doing that for your circuit, gives:

$$\omega_0=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{200\text{L}}{\text{C}}-1}}{10\sqrt{2}\text{C}}\tag2$$

With the condition that \$200\text{C}>\text{L}\$.

I found that using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
x = (1/(L*c))/(s^2 + s*(1/(R*c)) + (1/(L*c)));
R = 10;
s = I*\[Omega];
y = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[x]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[x]]^2], 
   Assumptions -> f >= 0 && L > 0 && c > 0];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{D[y, \[Omega]] == 0, \[Omega] > 0 && L > 0 && 
    c > 0}, \[Omega]], Assumptions -> L > 0 && c > 0]

Out[1]={{\[Omega] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[-1 + (200 c)/L]/(10 Sqrt[2] c), 
    200 c > L]}}
```

Now, you can solve for your values of \$\text{C}\$ and \$\text{L}\$ by solving the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{R}=10\\
\\
200\text{C}>\text{L}\\
\\
\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\cdot2\pi\cdot100\right)\right|=\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\\
\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\cdot2\pi\cdot1000\right)\right|=\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

And that gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{C}=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{20002}+101}}{198000 \pi }\approx0.0000250309\space\text{F}\\
\\
\text{L}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{20002}}-\frac{101}{20002}}}{10 \pi }\approx0.00143106\space\text{H}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

I found that using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
x = (1/(L*c))/(s^2 + s*(1/(R*c)) + (1/(L*c)));
R = 10;
s = I*\[Omega];
y = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[x]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[x]]^2], 
   Assumptions -> f >= 0 && L > 0 && c > 0];
\[Omega]0 = Sqrt[-1 + (200 c)/L]/(10 Sqrt[2] c);
a = y /. \[Omega] -> 2 Pi*100;
b = y /. \[Omega] -> 2 Pi*1000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{a == (y /. \[Omega] -> \[Omega]0)*1/Sqrt[2], 
   b == (y /. \[Omega] -> \[Omega]0)*1/Sqrt[2], 
   L > 0 && c > 0 && 200 c > L}, {c, L}]]

Out[2]={{c -> Sqrt[101 + Sqrt[20002]]/(198000 \[Pi]), 
  L -> Sqrt[-(101/20002) + 1/Sqrt[20002]]/(10 \[Pi])}}

In[3]:=N[%2]

Out[3]={{c -> 0.0000250309, L -> 0.00143106}}
```

Comment: OP is talking about the **crossover frequency**, that is where |H(jw)| = 0dB. What you find with \$\frac{\partial}{\partial\omega_0}\left(\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|\right)=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_0=\dots\$ and then \$|H(j\omega_0)| \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \$ is the corner/cut-off frequency, and not the crossover frequency.